# Run a script using a file as a parameter in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, parameters, scripting

I have been looking for this answer for a quite while but not exactly getting the right example or answer, that how can I run a script using a file as a parameter in linux I want to come up with something that if a user type for example this: `# ./script.sh check1.txt` in the bash so how it can automatically display the content of the file or make the appropriate script process. I am not sure whether I am explaining, right or wrong but this is the best I could. Give me any suggestions, examples or links. cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is pretty straight-forward, your script needs to use the command line arguments like this

```
# script.sh looks e.g. like this

infile=$1
second_param=$2

cat $infile > /tmp/$second_param
```

or whatever you like. then you call it like you expect:

```
./script.sh check1.txt
```

or

```
./script.sh check1.txt 123
```

if you need a second parameter